# Apache doesn't redirect subfolders

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm having trouble configuring my Apache server through the `.htaccess` file. I want to redirect all request from my domain (`example.com`, `www.example.com`, `example.com/folder1/folder2`) to my new domain (`new-example.com`, `www.new-example.com`, `new-example.com/folder1/folder2`).

My `.htaccess` looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Las directivas (líneas) entre «BEGIN WordPress» y «END WordPress» son
# generadas dinámicamente y solo deberían ser modificadas mediante filtros de WordPress.
# Cualquier cambio en las directivas que hay entre esos marcadores serán sobrescritas.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^android-chrome-192x192\.png /wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/android-chrome-192x192.png [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^android-chrome-512x512\.png /wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/android-chrome-512x512.png [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^apple-touch-icon\.png /wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/apple-touch-icon.png [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^browserconfig\.xml /wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/browserconfig.xml [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^favicon-16x16\.png /wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/favicon-16x16.png [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^favicon-32x32\.png /wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/favicon-32x32.png [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^favicon\.ico /wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/favicon.ico [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^mstile-150x150\.png /wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/mstile-150x150.png [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^safari-pinned-tab\.svg /wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/safari-pinned-tab.svg [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^site\.webmanifest /wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/site.webmanifest [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# My changes
DirectorySlash Off
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteOptions Inherit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ https://new-example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

When I access `www.example.com` everything works fine, I am redirected to `new-example.com` but when I access a **subfolder** inside the old domain (e.g. `www.example.com/subfolder1/subfolder2`) the redirect doesn't work.

Can anyone help me to find the mistake?

Comment: By "doesn't work", do you mean nothing happens or are you getting an error or incorrect redirect? Are there any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files in these subfolders? In the network traffic, are you seeing a "301" or some other status? Try changing `301` to `302` and clear your browser cache, has the response code changed in the network traffic? In short... the code you posted should already do what you require, so there must be "something else" going on.

Comment: @MrWhite, the point is: With my actual code if i access example.com everything works fine, and a 301 redirection occurs. however if i access to a subdirectory (example.com/subdirectory) nothing occurs and i'm still accessing to the old domain (example.com instead of new-example.com)

Comment: Yes, I got that from your question - the "document root" redirects OK. And `example.com` and `www.example.com` work the same in this respect it seems. What about the questions I raised in my previous comment... any other `.htaccess` files etc.? As I said, the problem is not with the rules you posted, so "something else" is causing this not to work. Do you have access to the server config?

Comment: You've tagged your question "WordPress" - so presumably you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: ...or have you removed all the existing WordPress directives? Do the old and new domains resolve to the same place or different servers?

Comment: @MrWhite, I have updated the question with the whole file. I think that there is not another ```.htaccess```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put your "redirect" directives in the wrong place - they need to go at the top of the file, *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section.

By placing them later in the file (after the WP front-controller) then they are only going to get processed for requests that map directly to physical files and directories (which includes the document root). So, in this case, I suspect `subfolder` is just a virtual path segment, not a physical subdirectory.

---

*Aside:*

I would also question why you've set `DirectorySlash Off` and included `RewriteOptions Inherit`?

You don't need to repeat the `RewriteEngine on` and `RewriteBase /` directives.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!